# How does the scoring work?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I cannot work out how the scoring works in game... Information is hard to come by, does anyone know what activities award points, and how much?

Comment: Kills, Plants, Defuses, Detonations, and maybe Assists are the likely candidates. No idea how much, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The points are distributed as follows:

- 2 points for a bomb plant. (Terrorist Only)
- 2 points if that bomb explodes. (Terrorist Only)
- 2 points for a kill.
- 1 point for an assist.
- 4 points for defusing a bomb. (Counter-Terrorist Only)
- 2 points for rescuing a hostage. (Counter-Terrorist Only)
- -1 point for killing a teammate.
- -1 point for committing suicide.

Comment: for completeness: killing teammates is negative points.

Comment: How many negative points for each kill? Are there minus points for killing hostages as well?

Comment: -1 for killing team members. not sure about hostages.

Comment: You also receive -1 for a suicide

Comment: For completeness: Are there extra points forexample a tripple kill?

Comment: No extra points for tripple kills and other "stunts"

Comment: What about deaths? do those count for points?

Comment: If you get killed, no. If you fall to your death or a badly thrown grenade -1 to your score.

Comment: Source? I can't find absolutely any official documentation.

Comment: Defusing the bomb seems to give 4 points, not 5. I tested by creating a private competitive match.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's been a few years since I played competitively. All the point values were gathered from in game when I was playing back then.

Answer (score 3):

The points are distributed as follows:

2 points for a bomb plant. (Terrorist Only)

2 points if that bomb explodes. (Terrorist Only)

2 points for a kill 3 when bomb planted

3 points for a kill when defending the bomb (Terrorist Only)

1 point when bomb detonate and you are alive

1 point when the bomb is defused and you are alive

1 point for an assist.

2 points for defusing a bomb. (Counter-Terrorist Only)

2 points for rescuing a hostage. (Counter-Terrorist Only)

-1 point for killing a teammate.

-1 point for committing suicide.

Comment: Someone already posted a similar answer.

Answer (score -2):

The points are distributed as follows:

- 2 points for a bomb plant. (Terrorist Only)
- 2 points if that bomb explodes. (Terrorist Only)
- 2 points for a kill 3 when bomb planted
- 1 point when bomb detonate and you are alive
- 1 point when the bomb is defused and you are alive
- 1 point for an assist.
- 2 points for defusing a bomb. (Counter-Terrorist Only)
- 2 points for rescuing a hostage. (Counter-Terrorist Only)
- -1 point for killing a teammate.
- -1 point for committing suicide.

up to date to 22.11.2015

Comment: Shouldn't this be an edit of the first answer? But then again, it adds something new.